# How to add lists to SelectBox in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a selectbox in libgdx , I am trying to add a list of values to it . Is the a way i can add the list such as selectbox.addAll(list1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [SelectBox reference](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/SelectBox.html) the method you are looking for is

```
    public void setItems(T... newItems)
```

You can use it for example like this:

```
    SelectBox.SelectBoxStyle boxStyle = new SelectBox.SelectBoxStyle();
    //creating boxStyle...

    String[] values = new String[]{"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"};
    SelectBox<String> selectBox = new SelectBox<String>(boxStyle);
    selectBox.setItems(values);
```

Of course instead of creating the style manually you can use [Skin](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin) with predefined .json file for this purpose